# For ______ of 63 years

Tags: single-word-requests

> He remained on the throne for a _________ of 63 years

What is the best word to fill in the gap. I've thought of **time** and **length** but they sound weird to me.

Comment: _Period_ or _reign_ come to mind, but I'm wondering why you want a word there anyway? _He remained on the throne for 63 years_ sounds just fine to me...

Comment: Could you clarify what sort of tone you are trying to set? If you want to be as neutral as possible I would just use "...for 63 years" but there are better answers if you want a tonal flourish.

Comment: What @oerkelens said. But suppose someone spoke the cited utterance (with or without a "missing word") - which you didn't hear clearly, so you said *I didn't catch that - what did you say was 63 years?*. Obviously the most sensible reply would be *His **reign**.*

Comment: Going by the tag info for ‘word choice’, this question is off topic because it doesn’t have a selection of candidate words, evidence of the OP having searched for alternative or context to guide judgement about suitable words. I’m not voting to close at present, but recommend the OP to read the Tag Info and sample questions and have a go at improving this one.

Comment: How about -- "he remained on the throne for 63 years"?

Answer (score 3):

Without rewording your sentence, I would suggest the word *span.*

*Span* is [defined as:](http://www.wordnik.com/words/span)

> n. The full extent or course over which anything is stretched or prolonged; the space or time covered or included between terminal points; entire reach from end to end or from side to side: as, the span of life; the span of a bridge.

*He remained on the throne for a span of 63 years.*

*Span* has the connotation of being an uninterrupted period and also of stretching across a long interval.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some possible words:

- **Period**: *"a length or portion of time"*.
  Period may also imply a sort of cyclical pattern. Some phrases that could be used are "63 year period of time", "63 year period of office", or "63 year period of incumbency"
- **Term**: *"a fixed or limited period for which something, e.g., office, imprisonment, or investment, lasts or is intended to last."*
  This word is typically used in political or government scenarios. Some phrases: "63 year term of office", and "63 year term of incumbency"
- **Duration**: *"the time during which something continues"*.
  This word should fit well in your example, because it pretty much implies you are going to give the amount of time.

Comment: Or, if the individual was notable for doing nothing, you could say "a coma of 63 years".